# How to get dynamic javascript HTML elements to interact with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program I am trying to make a drop down list. The problem that I am facing is that jquery does not recognise other HTML elements that I have created using dynamic JavaScript.

This is an example of what I am on about:

```
var notification_box = make_element("div", "Notifications: ", "notify");
notification_box.id = "notification_box";

console.log($("#notification_box"));

function make_element(tag, text, element_class)
{
     var element = document.createElement(tag);
     if(text != undefined)
     {
         var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
         nodeValue = text;
         element.appendChild(textnode);
     }

     if(element_class !== undefined)
     {
          element.classList.add(element_class);
     }
            
     return element;
}
```

what the console.log returns back is:

```
w.fn.init(0)
```

Comment: Search for event bubbling. There are also multiple dupes here on SO.

Comment: I would rather search for event delegation

Comment: if you want dynamically created element inside the Body of the page then you have to append that to body tag.

Comment: @ParamjotSingh DIRECTLY to the body tag?

Comment: @LaurentS. would this mean going through the document then the body tag and then for example a div, then another div and then reaching the destination (which could be a button for example). (The element I am looking for is DEEP down in the HTML).

Comment: @DaveNewton would this mean going through the document then the body tag and then for example a div, then another div and then reaching the destination (which could be a button for example). (The element I am looking for is DEEP down in the HTML).

Comment: What @ParamjotSingh is saying doesn't really make much sense. As for the other comments read [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)